# Is there an method similar to FFT for Fractionally Iterated Fourier Transforms?

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform, fractional-iteration

FFT is one of the 20th Century's greatest inventions, running as $O(n \log(n))$ rather than as $O(n^2)$ as a simple implementation of a discrete Fourier transform would.  But what about half-order Fourier transforms, or arbitrary real order iterated Fourier transforms?

Literature on this topic is quite sparse.

Comment: Fractionally iterated F.T. are an established thing in optics engineering. I'm no expert on it, but literature does exist on it, just not anything relevant that came up in my searches for a fast way similar to FFT to compute them.

Comment: Here is an open access article which is entitled [A Low-Complexity Approach to Computation of the Discrete Fractional Fourier Transform](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00034-017-0503-z).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the [Mehler kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform#Definition) has a FFT equivalent. An easy way to create a fractional FFT is to project $x$ onto the eigenspaces through $$P_k(x) = \frac14\sum_{l=0}^3 i^{-lk} F^l(x),\qquad P_k^2=P_k,P_mP_k=0$$ where $F^l$ is the FFT iterated $l$ times, then $S(x) = \sum_{k=0}^3 e^{2i\pi k/8} P_k(x)$ satisfies $$S^2(x)=\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k P_k(x)=F(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

After a little Google searching. I found a webpage
[The Fractional Fourier Transform](http://www.ee.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Ehaldun/wileybook.html)
about a book which seems to be very comprehensive and useful. The website states:

> Little need be said of the importance and ubiquity of the ordinary Fourier transform in many areas of science and engineering. As a generalization of the ordinary Fourier transform, the fractional Fourier transform is only richer in theory and more flexible in applications--but not more costly in implementation. This book provides a comprehensive and widely accessible account of the transform covering both theory and applications.

Also on the webpage is a link to
[Matlab code for fast computation of the fractional Fourier transform](http://www.ee.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Ehaldun/fracF.m)
which may be what you are looking for.